# How to use gemset in rbenv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv-gemset

I'm new to the concept of gemset and I'm trying to create a new gemset for my existing project.

I've installed the plugin and followed the steps as mentioned here

> https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset

Can anyone tell me what is the exact way to use the gemset in an existing project?

Comment: What do you really want to acheive by using gemsets? IMHO there is very few reasons outside of legacy non-bundler projects to use gemsets.

Comment: I'm trying to update my application and want to have different gemsets with different gem versions.

Comment: That's what bundler does for you anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Gemsets are nice if you work on multiple projects and don't want to pollute/break your global gemset when you install your various gems.

You can create a local file in your project dir like the docs say:

```
echo "my-cool-project" > .rbenv-gemsets
```

Now when you switch to that dir your project will use the gemset called `my-cool-project`